# Angular ngHint - expressions don't suport hyphens

Tags: javascript, angularjs, expression, angularjs-ng-hint

I've noticed this on 3.15-3.16 suddenly I started getting errors for expressions with hyphens (minus signs)

**Source:** `<div ng-click="Landing.goSlide(-1,4)"></div>`

**Error:** `Error: [$parse:ueoe] Unexpected end of expression: Landing.goSlide( {link…} at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP`

When I remove the `-` from before the 1 it works again, but I don't get why this broke in the first place.

### Update:

Found the culprit [ngHint](https://github.com/angular/angular-hint/blob/master/src/modules/events.js#L14) I'm not sure why angular is compiled with ngHint and I can't find how to remove ngHint. Any clues?

Comment: Maybe check if it's still an integer? could think it's a string. Just a guess.

Comment: I think `#{slideLength}` this is messing..

Comment: should be {{ ... }}?

Comment: Crap, forgot to mention that #{slideLength} gets turned into an integer at run time. I just updated it with what Angular sees. This worked previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out if you have the AngularJS Batarang extension enabled, it has ng-hint enabled by default and it will choke on any expressions that contain hyphens (and any other's that get split in the regex)

If anyone's curious, this is where it breaks.

```
var getFunctionNames = function(str) {
    if (typeof str !== 'string') {
        return [];
    }
    var results = str.replace(/\s+/g, '').split(/[\+\-\/\|\<\>\^=&!%~;]/g).map(function(x) {
        if (isNaN(+x)) {
            if (x.match(/\w+\(.*\)$/)){
                return x.substr(0, x.indexOf('('));
            }
            return x;
        }
    }).filter(function(x){
        return x;
    });
    return results;
};
```